# remove 404 errors from apache's master log file

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, http, httpd

Is there a way to prevent apache from filling up the log file with pointless error messages like 404's and only display real errors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.

For that you need to use the Apache module mod_log_config.

> Particular items can be restricted to print only for responses with
>   specific HTTP status codes by placing a comma-separated list of status
>   codes immediately following the "%". The status code list may be
>   preceded by a "!" to indicate negation.

Format String   Meaning

```
   %400,501{User-agent}i    Logs User-agent on 400 errors and 501 errors only. For other status codes, the literal string "-" will be logged. 

   %!200,304,302{Referer}i  Logs Referer on all requests that do not return one of the three specified codes, "-" otherwise.
```

The links is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html).